# Qt: How to implement a class for an image with properties

Tags: qt, qimage, qlabel

I have dared to start learning Qt with very basic C++ knowledge. I am asked to implement a class for image in Qt.

In my application whenever I will select a picture it will have some properties, such as, when I will move the window the QLabel that is containing my image will also increase in size of width and height without loosing the aspect ratio.

I do not expect some finished code. But I want to know how to think for that. I am having problem to make an algorithm.

I am expecting some help to solve this problem. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You should begin by running some sample code and seeing how they work. There are lots of examples that display images in various ways. Step through them to see if you can understand what each step does.

Try to write a simple "Hello world!" app in Qt. Then try adding an image display to it.  The solution to the task you describe should become straightforward as you develop knowledge of Qt.

Comment: Thanks I will start to do that.